# Url not showing expected content

Tags: iis, webserver

I have a webserver using IIS 7 that hosts multiple sites.  We've added a few subdomains recently and the one I'm working on WAS working.  It's only partially in production so I'm not sure when this problem came up.

The problem is the subdomain (vendor.domain.com) is pointing to another site on IIS (Mobile).

Advanced settings of Manage Web Site show the bindings to be correct:
`ftp:<ipaddr>:21:vendor.domain.com,http:<ipaddr>:80:vendor.domain.com,https:*:443:`.  The physical path is Vendors and has the files that I would expect it to be showing.  But...it's not.

I've gone to the "Mobile" site that it is being redirected to and edited the files there and the changes I've made there have NOT been reflected on the `vendor.domain.com` as I would expect.  It's like I have a cached version of the "Mobile" site.

Is there a way for me to find out where these files are coming from or a way to figure out why it's not showing the expected content?

Comment: You can right click and explore the site to see which directory is its root, Add a new test.html file to the site root and visit vendor.domain.com/test.html, to see which is being used if your still not clear.

Comment: Okay, tried this, good idea.  test.html returns a 404 although I can see it when I explore from the site.

Comment: Ok, place the file in the other site location and retry the url

Comment: @BhavO Okay, same result, 404.  (Maybe worth noting that the page did show up on the other site, though :) )

Comment: Are u doing these tests on the server itself (remote desktop) make sure your not doing remotely if you have load balanced web servers as you may be served content from another machine altogether. If you have two or more web sites they should differ by host header/IP/port combination, and should map to different physical locations.

Comment: @BhavO We do not have load based web servers and I am doing them on the server itself.  The changes are reflected immediately.  How can I check the host header/IP/port combination?

Comment: Basically the site bindings define the combo. You need to be eure which wire is pointing to which folder on disk and ensure they are not the same, also try recycle app pool or iisreset worst case

Comment: @BhavO OKAY!  I found the site that is hosting the actual files being used.  We also have an API site that is up and I was testing our mobile site there so it had the same files.  Changing the physical files on the API site changes the files shown on the vendor site.  But why would it act this way?  All the bindings look correct (vendor to vendor.domain.com and the correct IP, API to api.domain.com).  Whatsmydns.net shows vendor going to the correct IP shown in the bindings.

Comment: The way host headers work is that when you have multiple sites on same IP address and port, host header are used to distinguish them, so make sure your using the correct hostname when requesting the site in browser. DNS will have same IP for the different host names, the server it self sees the host header on the request and send the request to the matching site.